# Setting up MS graph calendar subscription returns "Access to OData is disabled"

Tags: microsoft-graph-calendar, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to use the subscription feature of the MS graph API to listen to changes in calendars. My app has Calendars.ReadWrite permission to all users set up in Azure, and reading and writing calendar events works well for all users with the access token I've obtained for my app.
However, when calling the POST /subscriptions endpoint to subscribe to changes in one user's calendar, I get "Access to OData is disabled".

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions
{
  "changeType": "created,updated",
  "notificationUrl": "https://...my.endpoint...",
  "resource": "users/someone%40somedomain.com/events",
  "expirationDateTime": "2021-10-27T20:09:25.025Z",
  "clientState": "foo"
}
```

This gives the following error:

```
"code": "ExtensionError",
"message": "Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: Forbidden; Reason: Access to OData is disabled.]"
```

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), this endpoint requires only the same permissions as the subscribed entity, which in my case would be `Calendars.Read`.

What could be causing this? How do I debug this further to understand why I'm getting this error?
I found some pages suggesting to use PowerShell to modify an ApplicationAccessPolicy. Is this relevant, and is it only possible through PowerShell? Why would there be an obscure policy accessible only through PowerShell and not through the Azure console?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was due to the user for whom I was trying to subscribe wasn't in the proper security groups, which were mapped to application policy.

So it had nothing to do with the permissions of my client, but rather of the target user I was trying to subscribe to.